# useFieldArray with Material UI Select doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hook-form

I am trying to use useFieldArray for dynamic Select field of Material UI and react-hook-form. It works fine with TextField, but when used with Select it doesn't work..

What doesn't work..

1. Set `defaultValue` doesn't show in Select, but shows in TextField
2. Value selected on Select and inputted value in TextField doesn't come when click in Submit.

Here is the code of Select component

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  FormControl,
  FormHelperText,
  InputLabel,
  MenuItem,
  OutlinedInput,
  Select,
  SelectChangeEvent
} from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";
import { useFormContext, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import Placeholder from "./Placeholder";

export interface IOptionTypes {
  id: string;
  label: string;
  value: string;
}

interface IFormElementTypes {
  name: string;
  label: string;
  required?: boolean;
  defaultValue: string;
  options: IOptionTypes[];
  placeholder: string;
}

export default function MultiSelectField({
  name,
  label,
  required,
  defaultValue,
  options,
  placeholder
}: IFormElementTypes) {
  const {
    control,
    register,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useFormContext();

  // const defaultVal = control._defaultValues[name];

  const [selectedVal, setSelectedVal] = useState<string[]>([]);

  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent<typeof selectedVal>) => {
    const {
      target: { value }
    } = event;
    setSelectedVal(
      // On autofill we get a stringified value.
      typeof value === "string" ? value.split(",") : value
    );
  };
  const labelText = `${label}${required ? "*" : ""}`;
  const labelId = `multi-select-${name}`;
  return (
    <Controller
      name={name}
      defaultValue={defaultValue}
      control={control}
      render={({ field }) => (
        <FormControl fullWidth>
          <InputLabel
            shrink
            sx={{ backgroundColor: "white", padding: "0px 2px" }}
            error={!!errors[name]}
            id={labelId}
          >
            {labelText}
          </InputLabel>
          <Select
            {...field}
            label={labelText}
            labelId={labelId}
            value={selectedVal}
            displayEmpty
            multiple
            {...register(`${name}` as const)}
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
            error={!!errors[name]}
            input={
              <OutlinedInput
                id={`multi-select-${label}`}
                label={`${label}${required ? "*" : ""}`}
              />
            }
            renderValue={
              selectedVal.length > 0
                ? undefined
                : () => <Placeholder>{placeholder}</Placeholder>
            }
            onChange={handleChange}
          >
            {options.map((option) => (
              <MenuItem key={option.id} value={option.value}>
                {option.label}
              </MenuItem>
            ))}
          </Select>
          <FormHelperText>{String(errors[name]?.message ?? "")}</FormHelperText>
        </FormControl>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

and How it is been called finally

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  useForm,
  useFieldArray,
  FormProvider,
  SubmitHandler
} from "react-hook-form";
import { Button, Grid, Stack, Box } from "@mui/material";
import MultiSelectField, { IOptionTypes } from "./MultiSelectField";
import TextFieldElement from "./TextFieldElement";

type FormValues = {
  items: { name: string; age: string }[];
};

const defaultValues = {
  items: [{ name: "john", age: "10" }]
};

const names: IOptionTypes[] = [
  { id: "1", label: "John", value: "john" },
  { id: "2", label: "Smith", value: "smith" },
  { id: "3", label: "Julia", value: "julia" },
  { id: "4", label: "David", value: "david" }
];

export default function App() {
  const methods = useForm<FormValues>({
    defaultValues,
    mode: "all"
  });
  const { control, formState, setError } = methods;

  const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({ name: "items", control });

  const formSubmitHandler: SubmitHandler<FormValues> = async (
    data: FormValues
  ) => {
    console.log("Form values ", data);
  };

  return (
    <Grid container>
      <Grid item xs={12}>
        <Stack direction="row" spacing={2} my={2}>
          <Button
            variant="outlined"
            color="primary"
            type="submit"
            disableElevation
            fullWidth
            onClick={() => {
              append({ name: "", age: "" });
            }}
          >
            Add Field
          </Button>

          <Button
            variant="outlined"
            color="primary"
            type="submit"
            disableElevation
            fullWidth
            onClick={() => {
              remove(fields.length - 1);
            }}
          >
            Remove Field
          </Button>
        </Stack>
      </Grid>

      <FormProvider {...methods}>
        <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(formSubmitHandler)}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Stack spacing={2}>
              {fields.map((field, index) => (
                <Stack direction="row" spacing={2} key={field.id}>
                  <MultiSelectField
                    name={`items.${index}.name`}
                    label="Choose Name"
                    placeholder="Name"
                    defaultValue=""
                    options={names}
                  />
                  <TextFieldElement
                    name={`items.${index}.age`}
                    label="Input Age"
                    placeholder="Age"
                  />
                </Stack>
              ))}
            </Stack>
          </Grid>
          <Grid container my={2}>
            <Grid item>
              <Button
                variant="outlined"
                color="primary"
                type="submit"
                disableElevation
                fullWidth
              >
                Save Changes
              </Button>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </form>
      </FormProvider>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```

As in the code above, I have set default values, which works for TextField but not for the SelectField

[image]

I wonder what is wrong in there..

Here is my Codesandbox, thanks for help.

[image: Edit Controlled field array (forked)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to make sure that you set the `value` prop on your `Select` inside of `MultiSelectField` to `selectedVal`:

```
<Select
            {...field}
            label={labelText}
            labelId={labelId}
            value={selectedVal}
            displayEmpty
            multiple
            {...register(`${name}` as const)}
            variant="outlined"
            fullWidth
            error={!!errors[name]}
            input={
              <OutlinedInput
                id={`multi-select-${label}`}
                label={`${label}${required ? "*" : ""}`}
              />
```

Also remove the `defaultValue={defaultValue}` from the `Controller` in `MultiSelectfield` so the `Controller` looks like this:

```
    <Controller
      name={name}
      control={control}
      render={({ field }) => (
```

Since you are using controlled components, we need to make sure we set the default value of `selectedVal` to the default value passed in as a prop:

```
const [selectedVal, setSelectedVal] = useState<string[]>(defaultValue);
```

`selectedVal` is supposed to be a `string[]` not a `string`, so we should change the type of `defaultValue` to a `string[]`:

```
interface IFormElementTypes {
  name: string;
  label: string;
  // eslint-disable-next-line react/require-default-props
  required?: boolean;
  defaultValue: string[];
  options: IOptionTypes[];
  placeholder: string;
}
```

Finally, back in `App.tsx` we should pass an array to `MultiSelectField` as the `defaultValue` prop. Here's what it would look like if we wanted "John" to be selected by default:

```
<MultiSelectField
                    name={`items.${index}.name`}
                    label="Choose Name"
                    placeholder="Name"
                    defaultValue={["john"]}
                    options={names}
                  />
```

Or, if we wanted to have the default be "John" **and** "Smith" then we could set the default like this:

```
defaultValue={["john", "smith"]}
```

Here's a full working example on CodeSandbox: [image: Edit Controlled field array (forked)]

Comment: Amazing.. Thanks for help.. But I was in impression setting defaultValue should automatically populate the values, but yes since we are using selectedVal that should contain the value..

Comment: No problem. If we were using `Select` as an uncontrolled component, then `defaultValue` would work, but since we're using a controlled `Select` `defaultValue` doesn't get used.